# javascript access mobile camera's flashlight

Tags: javascript, html

I'm doing research to know whether can access mobile device camera's flashlight with javascript.
Wanted to access flashlight from a mobile site, I know Cordova is able to do that, but that is for mobile application only I suppose. 
I have done some googling, but seems like there's no such thing, so would like to get confirmation or feedback from everyone else. 
Thanks.

Comment: Found this https://github.com/w3c/mediacapture-image, but not sure if it works...

Answer (score 0):

You can check if your browser supports flashlight by getting `PhotoCapabilities`.
The page below suggests that flashlight is currently supported in Chrome Android but iOS.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PhotoCapabilities